# Postfix and Spamassassin don't start on boot after Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade

Tags: server, upgrade, postfix

I have just upgraded a server from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.

My issue is that now upon reboot, neither Postfix nor Spamassassin are running.

There are init.d scripts for both these services and the services do start if I manually run commands like

```
sudo service postfix start
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix
sudo service spamassassin start
sudo /etc/init.d/spamassassin
```

and there are all the appropriate symlinks from /etc/rc[0123456].d/ to the init.d scripts.

After boot, there are no 'postfix', 'spamassassin' or 'spamd' entries in /var/log/mail.log or /var/log/syslog until I manually start Postfix and Spamassassin.

Update (2016_09_04): It seems that Postfix does start eventually (after 4 or 5 minutes) if not immediately. However, even 45 minutes after a reboot, spamd is still not running but starts immediately following 'sudo service spamassassin start'.

Answer (score 10):

Solved: The missing piece was

```
systemctl enable spamassassin.service
```

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd so you need to change your commands to the systemd versions. On systemd systems you use ...

```
systemctl COMMAND SERVICE
```

This to list all available services:

```
systemctl list-units --type=service --all
```

So for postfix that would be ...

```
systemctl start postfix.service
```

And logging is done with

```
journalctl -u postfix
```

Same applies for spamassassin.

Comment: Either you misunderstand my issue or I misunderstand your answer. My issue is not with the commands to manually start/stop services. My issue (currently) is that spamassassin doesn't start automatically following a system restart.

Comment: When spamassassin is installed on Ubuntu 16.04 via 'apt-get install spamassassin', a SYSV init.d script is installed in /etc/init.d/spamassassin. My understanding is systemd should handle those scripts and it apparently does as I have lots of them and the manual stop/start commands work and the services that are supposed to start automatically on reboot all do, except spamassassin.